# Django's objects.all() kills python

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project. There is `MyModel` in `models.py`. There are 4 000 000 instances of this model.

I perfom this script:

```
for m in MyModel.objects.all():
    if len(m.phone) < 10 or len(set(m.phone)) <= 2:
        m.delete()
```

But, it kills python (just prints 'Killed').

I know, the problem is in number of instances.
But how can i iterate all of them?

Comment: May I ask which task requires iterating over all objects? You may be better off with a batch operation at database level, or a clever query. As I write, another computer is chewing through 4 million files; trust me, this is a large enough amount of data that you don't want to touch all of it, *especially* not on a regular basis.

Comment: There is `phone` `CharField` in `MyModel`. I want to remove all instances with `len(set(phone)) <= 2 or len(phone) < 10`. I don't know how to make a query for it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to count objects first, and them iterated with sliced version. Something like:

```
step = 10
count = MyModel.objects.count()/step
for i in xrange(count):
    for m in MyModel.objects.all()[i*step:(i+1)*step]:
        # doing something with m
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. It looks like a dirty hack, but it works)

Comment: Nitpick: you'd be missing out on some entries, if count % step != 0.

Answer (score 4):

If you use [`iterator()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iterator) instead of `all()`, Django will not cache the queryset, which should reduce memory usage and boost performance.

```
for m in MyModel.objects.iterator():
    # doing something with m
```

Comment: Good advice, i didn't know about django's objects.iterator(). But it also kills python.

Answer (score 0):

Alexey's answer is pretty nice but he suppose the remainder of `MyModel.objects.count()/step` is zero
So, he may leave out some fields...

```
step = 10
total = MyModel.objects.count()  
count = total//step  
if (total % step != 0):    
    count += 1 


for i in xrange(count):  
    first = i*step  
    last = first + step - 1  
    if last >= total:  
        last = total  

    for m in MyModel.objects.all()[first:last]:
        # doing something with m
```